# How to sort column values in a pivot dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

i have created a pivot table from a dataframe with these lines of code:

```
df_multi_level = pd.pivot_table(df_raw_final, values=['weight'], index=['mb_assetclass', 'mb_categoriastrumento', 'asset_Name'], aggfunc=np.sum)

df_multi_level = df_multi_level.sort_values(by='mb_assetclass', ascending=False)
```

and i have this pivot table:

[image]

I want to sort the values of column 'weight" from largest to smallest while preserving the grouping of 'mb_assetclass' and 'mb_categoriastrumento' (largest from smallest)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset index by [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to bring back the columns previously set as index during `pivot_table()` before sorting.

Then sort with multiple columns and set parameter `ascending=` with the desired `True/False` values separately, as follows:

```
df_multi_level = df_multi_level.reset_index()

df_multi_level = df_multi_level.sort_values(['mb_assetclass', 'mb_categoriastrumento', 'weight'], ascending=[True, True, False])
```